# How to rethrow an array of validation errors returned by the class-validator's validate function?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I'm using the validate function offered by the class-validator library. Basically it returns an array of `ValidationError` objects:

```
export declare function validate(object: object, validatorOptions?: ValidatorOptions): Promise<ValidationError[]>;
```

I need to do something like:

```
try {
    await validate(RegisterFighterDto);
} catch (err) {
    // something like throw new HttpException(err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

but the above written piece of code won't work for a few reasons, one of the reasons being that the validate function doesn't throw an error, it just returns an array of error objects. I need to show them to the client in the standard way.

What should I do?

Comment: I am not sure why are you using validate inside a Function. The common way is to use a validation Pipe in the controller when you are recieving the dto. You can check one example here  https://github.com/fazd/nestjs-checklist/blob/main/src/tasks/tasks.controller.ts

Comment: I sure did read the docs. There's a very compelling reason why I'm doing it this way, that's the only way I can achieve dynamic validation, that's to say, to handle the case when there's a bunch of dtos and you never know which one is to be validated. I got to check the type based on a certain field's value and then validate it by using this function.

Comment: @FabioZapata However, all this is beyond the scope of this question, all I'm asking here is how to re-throw the array of errors returned by that function.

Comment: @Albert Can you show us a sample of `ValidationError` object ?